# Attempted to access b(1,2); index out of bounds because size(b)=[3,1]

Tags: matlab

I have a uni assignment to create a very basic function that works the same as the backslash command in MATLAB. I'm not looking for the answer to the uni, my intentions are not to cheat, I'm just stuck on a problem and need guidance on how to get this to work.

So I think I'm close to the answer.

```
function x = matrix_solve(A,b)
invA=inv(A);

[m,n] = size(A); % m is num rows, n is num of columns
nb = size(b,1);

if m == n && nb == m
    x = zeros(m,n);

    for i = 1:m
        for j = 1:n
            x(1,j) = x(1,j)+ invA(i,1)*b(1,j);
        end
    end
else
   error('Error')
end
```

Using a basic square matrix

```
b = [1;3;2]
A = [3,1,2;3,2,1;3,3,3]
```

I keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

I'm pretty familiar with other code but I'm very very new to Matlab.

Comment: The error message told you everything you need to know. Matlab tried to access `b(1,2)` but it couldn't, because `size(b)=[3 1]`, so you can only do `b(1,1)`, `b(2,1)` and `b(3,1)`. So, find where you have written `b(1,2)`, and replace it by `b(2,1)` (and so on in other places where you may have done the same thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of the index out of bound error is you're trying to access an element that doesn't exist at this line

```
    x(1,j) = x(1,j)+ invA(i,1)*b(1,j);
```

Instead it should be

```
    x(1,j) = x(1,j)+ invA(i,1)*b(j,1);
```

I.e. just change `b(1,j)` to `b(j,1)`. `b`is a column vector of size 3 (`size(b)=[3,1]`) and you are trying to access an element at row 1, column 2, but there is only 1 column.

Comment: Oops, just figured out, you were faster to answer. Could you please shortly elaborate *why* exactly it is `b(j,1)` and not `b(1,j)` so the OP knows where his/her mistake was?

Comment: Just added an additional line for explanation.

Comment: Thanks, this got rid of the error. Just not getting the same result as using A\b which is strange. I better keep working on it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @GenGen keep an eye on exactly this issue: Which elements - what row and column - do you want to use in every step of the for-loops.